# Is there a notice board on EESE?

Tags: feature-request

I shall be attending the funeral service for Barrie Gilbert (known for the [Gilbert Cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_cell) and for his [translinear theory from 1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translinear_circuit).) This is the [obituary for Barrie Gilbert](https://obits.oregonlive.com/obituaries/oregon/obituary.aspx?n=barrie-gilbert&pid=195483860). After the memorial service, Professor Tom Lee of Stanford, many Analog Devices engineers from both Massachusetts and Beaverton, as well as Tektronix and Maxim engineers will meet at *vintageTEK* for a social gathering.

I suspect there may be interest in such notices to some members and readers of EESE and wondered if there was an appropriate notice board of some kind here? And if not, how I might suggest the concept for consideration?

Answer (score 2):

Please, no. The reason I love Stack Exchange is because the near-exclusive focus on the *questions* and the *answers*, and that it downplays the community aspects. The chat is bad enough.

There are a countless number of traditional "bulletin boards" (see, even the name fits) online where this type of information would be more suitable. *All About Circuits* and the *EEVblog* forum comes to mind.

Comment: I'm thinking, in particular, of letting EESE participants be aware. For example, I know at least one some live close by and would very much like to know and they don't participate elsewhere. I suppose, assuming it doesn't exist, that it would need to be submitted to a vote. That is, after I ask for it. But I take your response as the first NO vote, I guess. Thanks for your thoughts about this.